# Change-of-variable method for a joint density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the following joint density function:

$f_{I,R}(i,r) = \frac{1}{ab}$
if $0<i<a$, $0<r<b$ and $0$ otherwise.

I need to get the density probability function of $Z=RI^{2}$. I'm stucked since the beginning because I don't see how to apply the change of variables theorem when is needed to convert from high to low dimension.

Comment: Have you tried computing $F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z)$ then taking a derivative? That's the standard approach.

Comment: You can add another function $W = W(R, I)$ and then apply the change of variables theorem to $(Z, W)$. $W = R$ works.